Browser won't save Cookie until page is refreshed
We have a React web application that communicates with an API server. The API server is on a different machine, but on the same domain (app.mydomain.com and api.mydomain.com). The API server is trying to set a Cookie that it expects the browser to send back on the next API request.
When the user first logs in to the site, the browser isn't saving the cookie. We can see that the server is sending it if we inspect the headers, but the browser doesn't save it. We can do any number of subsequent requests, and each time the cookie is ignored.
Then all I have to do is press the Refresh button in my browser, and it starts to work. It saves the next cookie and all subsequent new cookies. It continues to work until I log out again.
We've tried this in three browsers, Chrome, Safari and Firefox, and see the same behavior in each.
We have also tried every possible value of SameSite on the cookie and we've tried setting the Domain property, but those don't fix the problem, and really they shouldn't since the cookie itself is fine once we refresh.
I'm very puzzled by this and wondering what could possibly be causing such behavior.
Frank
